# Cooking on top of hob covers

Tags: electric-stoves

I've recently moved into a new flat and the oven has very rusty iron hobs. I've bought some stainless steel hob covers to hopefully protect them and keep them clean (as I don't fancy cleaning a rusty iron block). But I was wondering if I could keep the covers on while cooking. I'm pretty sure the cover won't melt, and as it is steel should be nicely conductive. I don't care if the steel changes colour because of the heat because that's still better than the rusty hob.

So basically would it be **safe** to cook with the hob covers still on the hob?

The covers are just ASDA Hob Covers.

Comment: Gas? electric? How about a photo of the problem?

Comment: Just clean up the iron hobs.

Answer (score 2):

Those covers are only for cosmetic appearance, they are not a cooking surface. It is not safe to cook with hob covers on:

- If you are using a gas hob the covers could block airflow and put the flame out. Gas gushing into your kitchen is a bad thing
- The metal is way too thin to handle high heat, it will probably warp when heated, perhaps enough to tip a light pan off. You don't want pans of boiling water or hot oil shifting around

Even if it was safe you wouldn't get a better cooking result as you are blocking the transfer of heat from the source to the pan. You are better off removing them before cooking.